# StreamListener cannot seem to work with Message type

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

We have an application the consumes messages from Kafka and process it. We are using Spring boot **2.2.6.RELEASE**, and Spring cloud **Hoxton.SR4**.

I am trying to receive a simple message:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "config": {
      "credentials": {}
    },
    "id": "est-00001",
    "merchantKey": "test-00001",
    "name": "Test",
    "version": 7,
    "type": "PARTNER",
    "vendorNumber": "14"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "timestamp": -1,
    "partition": 8,
    "key": "test-00001",
    "offset": 105,
    "topic": "configure",
    "headers": []
  },
  "key": "00001",
  "messageType": "dent.set",
  "id": "abf75248-6fb0-4b57-a92c-74d4d3143cc0",
  "time": "2018-03-16T15:56Z"
}
```

And this is the model I am using to deserialise the message

```
package com.commercetools.tuev.marketplace.merchant.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyDescription;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Map;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MerchantMessage {
    public MerchantMessage(){}

    @JsonProperty("id")
    @JsonPropertyDescription("The message id, usually a random UUID")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("time")
    @JsonPropertyDescription("ISO-8501 timestamp of the event")
    private String time;

    @JsonProperty("key")
    @JsonPropertyDescription("The key has to always match the entity's id (product id)")
    private String key;

    @JsonProperty("messageType")
    @JsonPropertyDescription("The Message Type")
    private String messageType;

    @JsonProperty("payload")
    private Map<String, Object> payload;

    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    private Map<String, Object> metadata;
}
```

and all I get is the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.messaging.Message` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantInput.destination=merchantTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantInput.group=consumerGroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantInput.consumer.header-mode=none
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantInput.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.merchantInput.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantInput.consumer.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.merchantInput.consumer.max-attempts=1
```

**Function**

```
    @StreamListener(value = MerchantProcessor.INPUT)
    public void manage(Flux<Message<MerchantMessage>> message) {
        message
                .map(Message::getPayload)
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .subscribe(payload-> System.out.println("Consumed: "+payload));
    }
```

If I remove the flux, everything just works fine:

```
    @StreamListener(value = MerchantProcessor.INPUT)
    public void manage(Message<MerchantMessage> message) {
        Mono.just(message)
                .map(Message::getPayload)
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .subscribe(payload -> System.out.println("Consumed: " + payload));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@StreamListener` and annotation-based programming model has been deprecated for a while now and for the past several years we have fully migrated to a [functional programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages) which requires no annotations.

You can simply change your code to be

```
@Bean
Consumer<Flux<Message<MerchantMessage>> message> {
   return flux -> flux
                .map(Message::getPayload)
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .subscribe(payload-> System.out.println("Consumed: "+payload));
}
```

Your input binding by convention is named `message-in-0`. You can get more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_and_binding_names) as well.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, I have been wrestling to get it to work after a dependency upgrade, but it seems that I have no other choice but to either change to Spring Function or adopt the KStreams (I have managed to do that, except for the acknowledgement is a bit challenging)